# logout for facebook using graph Api in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I am using Graph api login work fine but i need to logout the facebook please guide me how to logout the facebook

thanks for advance

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Unless you request the offline_access privilege Facebook access tokens expire after a while anyway.

Answer (score 2):

just call logout method with ur initialized object

```
 [facebookObj logout:self];//facebookObj is the object which i initialized during login
```

Comment: thanks for your response i am not using  Facebook Connect api just i am using Graph Api....